# sjPlot - plot_model() change points color and lines [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, sjplot

I have a lmer model and want to plot the effect trend with the point data, but the function plot_model(), although is great at plotting what I want, seems very unflexible in terms of customization.

I want to change the colours and alpha of the points in the following plot:

```
model1<-lmer(NDVI~ fall_ai+spring_ai+SI+(1|colony),data=clm,REML=T)
plot_model(model1, type = "pred", show.data = T)
```

[image]
As well as change the CI lines from alpha colour to  dashed lines, like the example below:

[image]
How can I do it?

Comment: Use `ggpredict` to obtain the data.frame, then use `ggplot` as normal to get all the flexibility you need. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info) for lots of resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually ended up using lattice to do it, but do you want to write a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be using lattice to do it:

```
plot(Effect(c("fall_ai"),model1),
     colors="black",lwd=1.5,ylab="Spring NDVI",xlab="Autumn Aridity Index",
     ci.style="lines",main="",ylim=c(0.20,0.55),xlim=c(0,45))

trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1, highlight = FALSE)
print(panel.points(clm$fall_ai,pch = 16, cex = 0.7, col = "black"))
trellis.unfocus()
```